# Correct Way to Test for a Dynamic Property with NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dynamic, nunit

Writing tests in NUnit, it seems like it would be strait forward to test for the existence of a property on a dynamic object.

```
Assert.That(() => { var x = aDynamic.expectedProperty; }, Throws.Nothing);
```

However testing the converse is where I hit a sang.

```
Assert.That(() => { var x = aDynamic.unexpectedProperty; }, Throws.TypeOf<RuntimeBinderException>());
```

This throws an `NUnit.Framework.AssertionException` while I am expecting a `RuntimeBinderException` and despite how I try to mitigate this it never succeeds with the specific exception. Even when specifically caught.

```
Assert.That(
    () =>
    {
        try
        {
            var x = aDynamic.unexpectedProperty;
        }
        catch (RuntimeBinderException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    },
    Throws.TypeOf<RuntimeBinderException>());
```

Comment: I just tried all your examples, and they worked fine for me: both tests passed in an NUnit runner for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NUnit 3 has a `Has.Property` syntax that is much easier to use than testing if exceptions are thrown. For example, here is a simple test that tests the existence and non-existance of properties,

```
[Test]
public void DynamicPropertyTest()
{
    dynamic dyn = new
    {
        Name = "Rob",
        Country = "Canada"
    };

    Assert.That(dyn, Has.Property("Name"));
    Assert.That(dyn, Has.No.Property("Age"));
}
```

Comment: That is exactly the kind of syntax I was hoping existed for this. Now I'm running into an issue were I get an exception when testing for when the object HAS the property, but it is failing any way with a `DynamicViewDataDictionary` exception.

Comment: What version of NUnit are you using, what version of .NET and what are you using to run the tests? Does the sample code work for you? It does for me with latest NUnit and the NUnit VS Adapter.